# Running PHP script from server Android SDK

Tags: php, android

So, while looking up how to run a php script from an android app, I came across this code:

```
final String url = "http://example.com/creatd.php?nm=mytest";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //do something here
    }
```

Originally, I assumed that this would work because the client.execute executes the script in the url. However, what I did not realize until now was the HttpGet gets information from running the script. My PHP script does not provide information. It merely executes a task on the server(correct me if I am wrong on the Httpclient).

How would I make it so the client.execute merely executes the script instead of also trying to get information from it? I am assuming the reason why my app crashes is since the script does not return any information the value is null.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$str = $_GET['nm'];
mkdir($str,0700);
fopen($str."/".$str.".meb", "w");
file_put_contents($str."/".$str.".meb", "Hello, world!", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

EDIT: Just a question, why do people keep downvoting my questions? I researched my question and tried to use solutions, but the solutions provided didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u tried to execute ur php script in broswer?

Comment: Yes and it works fine.

Comment: ok what response u got in php script?

Comment: All it is supposed to do is create a folder and add a file to it.

Comment: It gets the name of the folder and file from using $_GET

Comment: "I am assuming the reason why my app crashes is since the script does not return any information the value is null. " Did you look at the logcat? I'm assuming that it is failing since you're executing it in the main thread

Comment: the PHP script is the one that has a problem so thats the one you need to include in this question, not the java code

Comment: can u post logs plz so that i can analyze the question well

Comment: @Ghost I don't know what the problem is, I am assuming it is a problem with the java code or how it is applied because the PHP script works fine.

Comment: @JesusS I am running the apk on my tablet device so I can't check that. EDIT: There are problems with running the APK in emulation so I can't check.

Comment: sidenote: actually you really dont need the `fopen` line since you're already using `file_put_contents`

Comment: i haven't coded android java for a while but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android) might help

Comment: @user3864563 can u post log?

Comment: do you have access to the code? Where is the code you are posting located? onClick? onCreate?

Comment: The code is located in the onclick of the button in the app. And, yes I have access to the code of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ghost, I found a solution to the problem and added it in a thread.

```
final String url = "http://example.com/perform.php?nm="+string;
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    try {
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                    String responseString = out.toString();
                    //..more logic
                } else {
                    //Closes the connection.
                    try {
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Again, thank you Ghost.